# How do increase a size (hdd) of an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have changed my instance from m3.small to m3.large but the space I see in the system is the same. I can't afford loosing any data and unfortunately I won't be able to change paths in the scripts so all that needs to remain the same. Any ideas?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

Answer (score 2):

`resize2fs` has what you're looking for - online resizing. You didn't mention much about your environment so this is a good starting point.

Comment: it is an amazon linux instance

Comment: I understand that, but is it EBS storage or the instance store? Either way, the command referenced should assist with what you need done.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so simple.  First of all the disk space included with your instance is ephermal.  If you are using ephermal storage, then everytime you shutdown your instance you loose everything.  Depending on your setup, you may have an instance setup with ephermal, or ebs volumes.  Chances are you are using EBS and not the storage included with your instance.  If this is the case follow this guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

If it is ephermal, you will need to relaunch the instance, and I believe you are actually moving from a m1.small to a m3.large as a m3.small does not exist.  The M1 small has 160gb of Ephermal Storage, a M3 large has 32gb of Ephermal SSD Storage.  If this is the case you are a considerable amount of disk space, and will need to make substantial adjustments to allow the new instance to start.